# auto upgrade visual c++ to visual 2010 with c#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, upgrade

how to upgrade visual c++ 6.0 project to visual studio 2010 with c# code . After that,  how to automaticaly build visual studio 2010 project and log error and warming to file with c# code.
thanks :)

Comment: Convert the C++ code to a working VS2010 project first. This can be tricky because VC6 is antiquated and non-conforming to current standards. Then you can consider how to port to C#, if you even need to.

Answer (score 0):

C# and C++ are substantially different languages with extremely different libraries.

You will never be able to do that; you need to rewrite your project from scratch in C#.  (or just stick with C++)